# why does my Popup-Window appear on the top left corner instead of where I clicked it?

Tags: html, css, popup

I want to create a blank document, where on each reload the "stars" (with popup text in it) have a random position on each site reload

Now the only problem I have is that my Popup Window keeps opening up in the top left corner instead of where the star is located at

Here are the important code snippets:

HTML:

```
<div class="clickToShowInfo">
        <div class="info">
            <a href="https://google.com">Click here to open google</a>
        </div>
        <img class="images" src="stars/star_1.png" id="imgID1"/>
    </div>

    <div class="clickToShowInfo">
        <div class="info">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
        </div>
        <img class="images" src="stars/star_1.png" id="imgID2"/>
    </div>
```

*Note:*
*I included two stars for referencing one to each other*

CSS:

```
.images {
    position: absolute;
}

.clickToShowInfo {
    position: relative;
}
.clickToShowInfo:active .info { visibility: visible; }
/* And hold by staying visible on hover */
.info:hover {
    visibility: visible;
}

.info {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: rgb(0, 47, 255);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #aaa;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 200px;
}

.info:active {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    left: -1000px;
    top: -1000px;
}
```

*Note:*
*.images is responsible for the  tag in the html file*
*the rest is for making the stars clickable through css only*
*note that if a star is already in the top left corner, the popup works just fine and doesnt disappear. you can hold down the mouse button and move to the popup and test how it works*

Javascript just in case:

```
function randomizeStars() {
    var arrayIDs = ["imgID1", "imgID2", "imgID3", "imgID4"];
    var amount = arrayIDs.length;
  
    for (i=1;i<=amount;i++) {
  
     var element = document.getElementById(arrayIDs[i-1]);
     var positionInfo = element.getBoundingClientRect();
     var imgHeight = positionInfo.height;
     var imgWidth = positionInfo.width;
  
  
     var screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
     var screenHeight = window.innerHeight;
  
     var imgLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * (screenWidth - imgWidth));
     var imgTop= Math.floor(Math.random() * (screenHeight - imgHeight));
  
     document.getElementById(arrayIDs[i-1]).style.top = imgTop+"px";
     document.getElementById(arrayIDs[i-1]).style.left = imgLeft+"px";
    }
  }

randomizeStars();
```

*Note:*
*I don't think the js is responsible for the error, but just in case*

I will include a screenshot too

I tried to change the order in which the classes appear in the tag attribute, but that stopped the random position from occuring.

Comment: You re setting the position of each img, not setting the position of its parent div. The position of the info knows nothing about the random img positioning.

Comment: @AHaworth How can I set that up? i cant add a double ID and otherwise I wouldnt know how to to achieve that